# How can I show a PowerApp in VSTS / Azure Devops dashboard?

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

There is a PowerApp that collects some data from developers. The most natural place for them to access it would be from Azure Devops, where they spend most of their day so ideally the app shows up right there.

How can I embed the PowerApp in a dashboard on Azure Devops dashboard?

The app is a standard PowerApp with a list and an edit form which connect to a SQL Database on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried this, but an idea.

Azure DevOps Dashboard allows to Embed web page which is like an iframe with url. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#embedded-web-page)

> Adds a configurable tile to display the contents of a web page. Only webpages that allow iframe embedding are supported.

Use the above webpage tile to embed the canvas app using its url. Canvas PowerApp will have an accessible url just like shown below:

```
https://web.powerapps.com/apps/299d486c5-487hg-47hg-9999-474mdmdn84u
```

[Reference](https://sachinbansal.blog/2018/06/17/powerapps-canvas-app-how-to-pass-parameter-in-app-url-display-data-based-on-parameter-passed/)

Comment: Thanks Arun, I tested it and technically it works indeed. However, with the webpage you get all the Chrome of the PowerApp webpage around it, which makes the actual app appear so small that it is hardly useful. Still, this is the only way I found so far.